# How to use strtok on char*

Tags: c++, split, c-strings, strtok, string-literals

In c++, to filter out the delimiter using `strtok`, the source has to be a char array, otherwise, it gives me a seg fault. How can I use `strtok` on a pointer to `char`?

Code example of how to structure `strtok`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string."; // this is the string i want to split. notice how it's an array
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Example of what I want to do:

```cpp
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char* str ="- This, a sample string."; // since this is a pointer to char, it gives a segmentation fault after compiling, and executing.
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't point it to a string literal, that might and will very likely be in read-only memory. Create a copy first, e.g. using `strdup` because `strtok` can and most likely will modify the string.

Comment: `strtok` modifies the C string it scans, putting null chars at the end of each token. Better avoid doing that on C-char arrays inside C++-strings. Use a copy.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string literal (the function `strtok` changes the source string inserting null characters `'\0'`)

```
char* str ="- This, a sample string.";
```

First of all in C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays. So you have to write the declaration of the pointer in a C++ program with the qualifier `const`.

```
const char* str ="- This, a sample string.";
```

Any attempt to change a string literal in C and C++ results in undefined behavior.

For example in the C Standard there is written (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

So it is always better also in C to declare pointers to string literals with the qualifier `const`.

Instead of `strtok` you could use for example C standard string function `strspn` and `strcspn`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "- This, a sample string.";
    const char *delim = " ., -";

    for (const char *p = s; *( p += strspn( p, delim ) ) != '\0'; )
    {
        auto n = strcspn( p, delim );

        std::string_view sv( p, n );

        std::cout << std::quoted( sv ) << ' ';

        p += n;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
"This" "a" "sample" "string"
```

You could for example declare a vector of string views like `std::vector<std::string_view>` and store in it each substring.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "- This, a sample string.";
    const char *delim = " ., -";

    std::vector<std::string_view> v;

    for (const char *p = s; *( p += strspn( p, delim ) ) != '\0'; )
    {
        auto n = strcspn( p, delim );

        v.emplace_back( p, n );

        p += n;
    }

    for (auto sv : v)
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted( sv ) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

Or if the compiler does not support C++ 17 then instead of a vector of the type `std::vector<std::string_view>` you can use a vector of the type `std::vector<std::pair<const char *, size_t>>`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "- This, a sample string.";
    const char *delim = " ., -";

    std::vector<std::pair<const char *, size_t>> v;

    for (const char *p = s; *( p += strspn( p, delim ) ) != '\0'; )
    {
        auto n = strcspn( p, delim );

        v.emplace_back( p, n );

        p += n;
    }

    for (auto p : v)
    {
        std::cout.write( p.first, p.second ) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
This a sample string
```

Or you could use a vector of objects of the type `std::string`: `std::vector<std::string>`.

In C you can use a variable length array or a dynamically allocated array with the element type of a structure type that contains two data members of the type `const char *` and `size_t` similarly to the C++ class `std::pair`. But To define the array you at first need to calculate how many words there are in the string literal using the same for loop.

Here is a C demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "- This, a sample string.";
    const char *delim = " ., -";

    size_t nmemb = 0;

    for (const char *p = s; *( p += strspn( p, delim ) ) != '\0'; )
    {
        ++nmemb;
        size_t n = strcspn( p, delim );
        p += n;
    }    

    struct SubString
    {
        const char *pos;
        size_t size;
    } a[nmemb];

    size_t i = 0;

    for (const char *p = s; *( p += strspn( p, delim ) ) != '\0'; )
    {
        size_t n = strcspn( p, delim );

        a[i].pos = p;
        a[i].size =n;
        ++i;
        p += n;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < nmemb; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.*s ", ( int )a[i].size, a[i].pos );
    } 

    putchar( '\n' );   
}
```

The program output is

```
This a sample string
```

Answer (score 0):

> Example of what I want to do:
>
> ```
> char* str ="- This, a sample string."
> ```

You cannot do what you want because string literals are not implicitly convertible to pointer to non-const char in C++. Furthermore, `strtok` modifies the argument string, and srtring literals must not be modified in C++.

> How to use strtok on c++ on char*

If you really want to, you can do this:

```
char str_arr[] ="- This, a sample string.";
char* str = str_arr;
```

But it would be rather *pointless*.

---

In order to tokenise a string literal without copying it into a modifiable array, you must not use `strtok`.